# htaccess recursive mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I like to use mod_rewrite to essentialy rewrite a path that doesn't actually exist creating a virtual structure.  The problem that has been nagging me, is suppose I want to redirect  /articles/  , I find I must create a seperate rule for each sub folder and additionaly, in order to handle the paths with or without the / at the end, requires yet another rule, so 2 x the rules for every path or sub path I need to write a controller for.  An example is as follows of what I have been doing :

```
RewriteRule ^articles/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Additionally, I end up having to do stuff like this

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*)/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/$ /pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/$ /pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /pages.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

I may be stretching here, but this seems to be terribly inefficient, and logically, there must be a simple way to be able to handle the control of an entire sub folder and all of it's sub contents.

My question is this >>>  How can I simplify this into one line for each path that I wish to handle ?

Comment: `.*` will match _everything_, including `/`, so ^pages/(.*)$ /pages.php` is all that's needed. There is no need for the others. To make sure this applies to everything that doesn't actually exist, precede it with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: As for the first pair, make the trailing slash optional with `/?` That pair can be both covered with `RewriteRule ^articles/?$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: So the complete rule for "articles" would be

`RewriteRule ^articles/?.*$ /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]`   ?

Comment: If you aren't using any `()` groups as `$1,$2` etc, then you could just do `^articles(/.*)? /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]` because the `?` makes _everything_ following `articles` optional.

Comment: Is the idea here to just take any word at the start of the request URI, and if a corresponding `word.php` exists to rewrite into it with _no_ variables `$1,$2` etc?

Comment: Nice.  Thank you so much.  Saves tonnes of writing  :).  Why not post it as an answer so I can flag it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you're attempting is unnecessary, particularly because you are not making use of any `()` capture groups to pass variables (`$1,$2`, etc).

Since `.*` matches *everything* or *nothing*, that includes every subdirectory (virtual subdirectory) because it also matches `/`.

So if you want to match `/articles` followed by anything else, you may do so with:

```
 RewriteRule ^articles(/.*)?$` /articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

The `?` makes the entire `()` preceding group optional, so it may or may not include a trailing `/` _or anything else after it.

If you are attempting to match any starting word at the beginning of the request URI, and if it has a corresponding `.php` file to direct into that, you can use `-f` to test if that PHP file exists and rewrite into it if it does:

```
# If the requested file or directory doesn't actually exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite the first word (before the first dot or /) into word.php
# This one rule covers both /pages and /articles
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

If `word.php` does not exist, this will result in a 404.

```
# OR...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Alternatively to the very generic rule above, you can list the 
# available words in it. This way you would only allow certain scripts
# to be written into .php
RewriteRule ^(articles|pages)(/.*)?$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```